# Iterative binary search with only two comparisons?

Tags: c, binary-search

Adjust the iterative binary search code so that it uses only two comparisons instead of three (in
the main while loop). *Note: The three comparisons are in the while loop, and two if statements
within the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ItBinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {

    int first = 0;
    int last = len-1;

    while (first <= last){
        // Assert: array is sorted
        int mid = (first+last) / 2;

        if (target == arr[mid])
            return 1;

        if (target < arr[mid])
            last = mid-1;

        else first = mid+1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int arr[6]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int len=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int target = 4;
    printf("%d\n",ItBinarySearch(arr,len,target));
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you think you need to do. Binary search, by definition, takes O(log2(n)) comparisons. A comparison is any time you use ==, >, <, etc. *on data values* (comparing indices like first and last doesn't count).

Comment: A comparison is when you compare two things. I assume that in this context, a comparison is every `if`, every `else` every `while` because you do a comparison there. I guess the teacher wants you to rewrite the function so that only two comparisons are found in the function.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker if comparing first and last doesnt count, then doesnt it already have 2 comparisons? one for target == arr[mid] and one for target < arr[mid]

Comment: Yes, there are two comparisons inside the loop, and the loop is likely to be run O(log2(n)) times.

Comment: @Pablo Your answer seems to be different from Lee's. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @McBonzo We both are using "comparison" in a different context. Lee's talking about comparisons in the sense of runtime analysis, how many times two values are compared with each other in the average case. I'm talking about comparisons in C doing `==`, `!=`, etc. *how would I turn the following binary search algorithm into one with two comparisons* if that's the phrasing that your teacher used, then I  don't know what your teacher meant by that.

Comment: I've changed my question up

Comment: Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try moving one of the if/else statements outside the loop. Which if/else would be the most likely candidate where the algorithm would still work if it were outside the statement?

Comment: thanks! i just moved the == statement and it worked!